# How to save data without database and client side script

Tags: xml, excel, validation, client-side, form-submit

I want to collect our companies survey feedbacks using a html form.

I want to save the form data in a excel sheet or XML file with client side scripting only.
No serverside script can be used.

Is it possible ?

Comment: No, it isn't possible.

Comment: You'll need something to process the form, and write to the client machine.  JavaScript alone cannot do that.  You will have to use the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write files using JavaScript. There are no file functions in JavaScript. You need an server to do that (not necessarily, the same of the application).

Comment: Actually i did using PHP & MS EXCEL as my data storing file.

Comment: @thowzif Well, PHP is server side.